# Phonegap Build como mudar a versão do cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

Ao publicar meu aplicativo na google play o mesmo foi rejeitado, o motivo foi este:

> Alerta de segurança
>   Gostaríamos de informar que seu app foi criado em uma versão do Apache Cordova que contém vulnerabilidades de segurança. É necessário migrar o app para a versão 3.5.1 ou posterior do Apache Cordova assim que possível. A partir de 31/08/2015, o Google Play bloqueará a publicação de novos apps e atualizações que usem versões do Apache Cordova anteriores à 3.5.1.

Gostaria de saber se é possível mudar minha versão do Cordova, ou o que eu poderia fazer para sanar este problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, só atualizar a versão do seu Cordova. Na realidade você está usando o Phonegap certo?
Eu recomendo você criar os seus projetos via linha de comando, na minha opinião é melhor.
Instala o Node.js e logo após é só executar este comando:

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Para maiores detalhes você pode ver a documentação aqui:
http://phonegap.com/install/

Após fazer este processo é só copiar os seus arquivos para a nova pasta.

Comment: utilizei o phonegap para "criar" minha aplicação, mas mesmo assim continua me informando o mesmo problema, o phonegap está na versão 5.3.6

Comment: Mas você criou o projeto novamente? é necessário atualizar, e criar um projeto novamente, após isso só copiar os arquivos do WWW do seu projeto antigo e jogar no novo...

Comment: Para compilar o .apk, é possível pelo phonegap? ou tenho que usar o build?

Comment: Acredito que sim, particularmente eu utilizo o Cordova e faço tudo por comando de linha, minha opinião é bem melhor. Se você quiser dar uma olhada fiz uma postagem explicando o uso do Cordova: http://phpiando.com.br/criando-um-projeto-cordova-cli/

Comment: Agradeço as dicas, graças a sua ajuda pude identificar o erro, o mesmo encontrava-se no arquivo cordova.js, que em geral é gerado automaticamente pelo PGB.

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho que além de instalar o phonegap você também instale o npm install -g cordova caso esteja fazendo build local.